# converting from Jpeg 2000 to DICOM using DCMTK

Tags: dicom, jpeg2000, gdcm

I am tring to convert a DICOM with  JPEG 2000 Transfer Syntax to regular DICOM file (Explicit Little Endian, or Implicit Little Endian).

I was able to read pixels from DICOM / JPEG 2000 file into a buffer, but I am now stuck on to create JPEG 2000 dicom file using DCMTK library.

This is what i have to tried so far.

```
OFCondition isrep = datas->chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEG2000, NULL);

if(datas->canWriteXfer(EXS_JPEG2000,orxfer))
{
OFCondition  issaved = fileformat.saveFile("d:\\test.dcm", EXS_JPEG2000, EET_ExplicitLength, EGL_recalcGL,
                       EPD_noChange, OFstatic_cast(Uint32, 0), OFstatic_cast(Uint32, 0), EWM_updateMeta);
}
```

I am getting an error:

> pixel representation not found

Answer (score 4):

Did you install the private (commercial) [J2K module](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmjp2k.php.en) ? If not, DCMTK open-source does not support JPEG 2000. Instead you should use GDCM. Eg:

```
$ gdcmimg input.jp2 output.dcm
```

See [gdcmimg documentation](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmimg.html).